# How can i search TODO lines in javascript files with resharper?

Tags: resharper, bug-tracking, todo

I am writing javascript codes and i want to add todo, note, bug etc. to .js or .aspx files. But Resharper 4.5 couln't find them. Is there any way to show these comments inside todo explorer?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Platform: VS.NET 2008

[image: TODO in CS File]

[image: TODO in ASPX File]

Comment: You are writing javascript files in... Visual Studio...? IGNORING THAT: What's wrong with just writing `// @todo` and doing a global code search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper needs lexer to analyse comments. JavaScript is not yet supported in ReSharper, so there is no lexer and to-do items won't work there.

Updated: ReSharper 6 does support JS files and to-do items are extracted from such files.